# Mongo query to create a subform from json entry

Tags: json, mongodb

I want to only access a part of the document. Only **Variables** in the entry given below in the following format.

```
Document1:{
        "META" : {
            "CATEGORY" : "Boxes",
            "CREATEDBY" : "Garima",
            "PRIVACY" : "PUBLIC",
            "KEYWORDS" : [ 
                "day","night"
            ],
            "TEMPLATE_NAME" : "Name",

        "IS_ACTIVE" : true
    },
    "**Variables**" : **[ 


 {

            "INDEX" : 0,
            "DATATYPE" : "string",
            "NAME" : "varient text  type",

        }, 
        {

            "INDEX" : 1,
            "DATATYPE" : "number",
            "NAME" : "varient number type",

        }, 
        {

            "INDEX" : 2,
            "DATATYPE" : "price",
            "NAME" : "varient price type",

        }, 
        {

            "INDEX" : 3,
            "DATATYPE" : "date",
            "NAME" : "varient date type",

        }, 
        {

            "INDEX" : 4,
            "DATATYPE" : "text",
            "NAME" : "varient textarea type",

        }, 
        {

            "INDEX" : 5,
            "DATATYPE" : "string",
            "NAME" : "varient blank radio type",

        }, 
        {

            "INDEX" : 6,
            "DATATYPE" : "string",
            "NAME" : "varient single radio type",

        },**
```

Output Required

```
**Variable Names [varient text type,varient number type,varient price type,varient date type,varient textarea type,varient blank radio type,varient single radio type]**
```

I have used `db.collection.find({Variables})` but doesn't show as it is an array.
Later I want these names to create a form in meteor using autoform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS File:

```
var variant=CollectionName.find( { "VARIENTS.NAME": 1, _id : 0 } );
```

HTML File:

```
          {{#each variant}}
            <li>
              {{#each VARIENTS}}
           {{this.NAME}}
           {{/each}}
            </li>
           {{/each}}
```

This will display the variant names only.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output and sample data are not matching.

Is it what you are looking for-

```
db.collectionName.find({},{"Variables.INDEX":1,"Variables.DATATYPE":1,"Variables.NAME":1, "_id":0})
```

Above query will gives following output with sample data provided in question.

```
{
    "Variables" : [
        {
            "INDEX" : 0,
            "DATATYPE" : "string",
            "NAME" : "varient text  type"
        },
        {
            "INDEX" : 1,
            "DATATYPE" : "number",
            "NAME" : "varient number type"
        },
        {
            "INDEX" : 2,
            "DATATYPE" : "price",
            "NAME" : "varient price type"
        },
        {
            "INDEX" : 3,
            "DATATYPE" : "date",
            "NAME" : "varient date type"
        },
        {
            "INDEX" : 4,
            "DATATYPE" : "text",
            "NAME" : "varient textarea type"
        },
        {
            "INDEX" : 5,
            "DATATYPE" : "string",
            "NAME" : "varient blank radio type"
        },
        {
            "INDEX" : 6,
            "DATATYPE" : "string",
            "NAME" : "varient single radio type"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This will display only first index, how about having multiple variables

Comment: @garima did u tried it? It will gives you all objects in `Variables`. See my edit for output generated by query.

Comment: ya but to display changes had to be made in HTML as well